# Can Adware and other programs be downloaded onto your pc when its asleep?

Tags: windows-7, adware

I left work and had 2 days off when i can back my laptop was infected with ad ware upon looking into i found out that the ad-ware had been installed on a day i wasn't at work, is it possible for ad-ware and other software to be installed while your pc is asleep?? or do i need to update my security as someone has clearly been using my pc?

Comment: No, nothing happens when your PC is asleep. Nothing gets installed or removed. In fact, your computer does nothing other than supply a little voltage to the system memory (and some other components) so it can retain its data.

Comment: As you say, someone may have been using your PC. Use *Event Viewer* to see when your PC was powered on/off while you were away. Also possible is that the adware was already there some time ago but lay dormant until now. That's not an uncommon thing.

Answer (score 6):

When the computer is asleep, very few things are going on system-wise (relatively).  In this state, malware cannot be downloaded.

However, it is entirely possible for your computer to come out of sleep while you are not aware.  Certain scheduled tasks can wake the computer from sleep, as well as Wake On Lan, and things like your cat playing with the mouse or keyboard.

Comment: Windows Update can also bring the computer out of sleep, or someone who has access to the laptop could potentially do harm to it.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible that your system was comprimised at an earlier point in time and the installation was scheduled with the task manager, which would have woken your computer from sleep.